# Font in XML using Support Library 26.1: Rendering Issues

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-xml

I decided to use the [Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) feature to use **one** custom font in my app. I ensured the following are done:

- Use of Support Library 26.1.0 (Since I'm targeting API level 19 & above)
- Gradle files are in sync
- Font is directly added in XML, and not programmatically

  Instruction are followed accordingly as provided in the link

Everything works fine and I can see the custom font being used on my `Buttons` when I run my app in a virtual device.
However, after applying the custom fonts in XML, two warnings popped up:

- Layout fidelity warning
- Failed to instantiate one or more classes

How do I get rid of those warnings? If I can't, are they safe to ignore?

---

App's Gradle file (Partial):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile "com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0"
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ks.shakee.MainMenuActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_mainmenu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_vertical_invisible_medium"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_timedgame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
            android:text="Timed Challenge"
            android:textSize="32dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_bestscore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"
            android:text="Best Score"
            android:textSize="32dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="66dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="231dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated my Android Studio to 3.1 today and changed my Gradle file to use 27.1 instead. The warnings are gone.